# Swift3.1 - NSApplication.terminate or NSApplication.shared().terminate

Tags: swift3, xcode8

Creating a StatusBarMenuItem using a older style, what works fine. However because of a warning, I did want to change my code conform Swift 3.1, from

```
menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Quit terminate", action: Selector(("terminate:")), keyEquivalent: "q" ))
```

to

```
...
menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Quit quitAction", action: #selector(quitAction), keyEquivalent: "Q"))
...
func quitAction() {
        NSApplication.shared().terminate(self) // works of course
       // NSApplication.terminate(self) // doesn't works of course but works in a selector
    }
```

Then I found out that they did change the Selector(("terminate:)) part not only to #selector but also the terminate part into

```
menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Quit NSAppl.terminate", action: #selector(NSApplication.terminate(_:)), keyEquivalent: "q" ))
```

But the following is also working ( mind the '.shared()' part )

```
menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Quit NSAppl.shared.terminate", action: #selector(NSApplication.shared().terminate(_:)), keyEquivalent: "q" ))
```

But when I want to remove the .shared() part from the quitAction function then I get a compiler error. My question is; "Why can I leave the shared() part out using a selector but not in a line of code"? What is the rationale about this? Thank you.

Actually, the question should be more like; "Why can I insert the shared() part using a selector"?

added image
[image: 4 ways of terminate an statusBar app using menuItems actions]

Comment: Does the "Quit NSAppl.shared.terminate" menu item work as expected when you click it? I suspect it'll give an "unrecognized selector" error at runtime

Comment: Yes, all 4 way's are working fine. No error. I will try to add an image.

Answer (score 0):

A selector with syntax `Type.method` sends the `method` to an **instance** of the `Type` specified in the `target` parameter.

I suppose in macOS a selector **without** specified target is sent to `FirstResponder` ignoring the `Type`. The method `terminate:` is exposed to `FirstResponder`

In code you have to send the method to an instance so `shared()` is required.